# SQL identity не работает

Tags: mysql, sql

Пробую создать таблицу с полем id с атрибутом identity, но постоянно выскакивает ошибка. Что я делаю не так?

```
CREATE TABLE Organisation (
EmployeeID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
EmployeeDepartment varchar(30) NOT NULL,
ProjectDirection varchar(30) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_Organisation PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT UQ_Organisation_EmployeeName UNIQUE (EmployeeName)
);
```

Текст ошибки

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1), EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL, EmployeeDepartment varchar(3' at line 2

Comment: @RomanKonoval,  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1),  EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,  EmployeeDepartment varchar(3' at line 2

Comment: IDENTITY - это в SQL Server. В MySQL используется AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL нет команды `IDENTY`. Вместо нее есть ключевое слово `AUTO_INCREMENT` вместе с модификатором `NOT NULL`. Таким образом команда создания таблицы должна быть такой:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Organisation (
EmployeeID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
EmployeeDepartment varchar(30) NOT NULL,
ProjectDirection varchar(30) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_Organisation PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT UQ_Organisation_EmployeeName UNIQUE (EmployeeName)
);
```

Comment: просто в SQL SERVER MANANGMENT STUDIO, когда вводишь то ошибки не выдает, а у workbench дает ошибку. Но все равно спасибо)

Comment: @Halland просто SQL Server Management Studio работает с **MS SQL Server**, а Workbench с **MySQL**. Это **различные** СУБД и у них немного отличается синтаксис SQL запросов